# I am trying to split this string based on space and some special characters like @,.,_,'..etc

Tags: java, string

I am trying to split this string based on space and some special characters like @,.,_,'..etc

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";

       // analyzing the string 
       String[] Val = str.split("[' '',@!_.]");// Split call

       // prints the number of tokens
       System.out.println("Count of tokens = " + Val.length);

       for(String token :Val) {
       System.out.println(token);
       } 
       }
```

I am getting out put as

```
Count of tokens = 11
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy

isn
t
he?
```

My question is why its taking a space as a character

Comment: What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: I think it's an empty character by comma ',' and empty space. It isn't a space. It 's 2 consecutive splits.

Comment: Count of tokens = 10
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he

Comment: String[] Val = str.split("[' '',@!_.]");\n

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why its taking a space as a character

If I take that question *literally*, the answer is that you've included a space in the character class, and so that's why it's splitting on a space.

But I think you mean, why is there a blank entry after "boy" and before "isn". The reason is that you've told `split` to split on those characters, and so it's doing so; since two of them appear next to each other (the comma and then space after "boy"), you're getting an entry in the resulting array that is `""`.

If you want it to split on one *or more* of those characters, add a `+` after the character class:

```
String[] Val = str.split("[' '',@!_.]+");// Split call
// here -----------------------------^
```

---

Side note: You've listed `'` *three separate times* in the character class. Just once is sufficient:

```
String[] Val = str.split("[' ,@!_.]+");// Split call
// Just one ---------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the example, while using regular expression I found same output with blank space.Here, I stored resultant words in a list tried to eliminate the **null** or **blank**.

```
 if(p != null && p.length() > 0) {
         list.add(p);
      }
```

restored list in to original array.

```
words = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Which ultimately solved the problem statement.Here is the complete code.Try to execute it and give the same line as input using scanner.

```
import java.io.*;
```

import java.util.*;
public class StringTokens {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String delim ="[\\s+|.,?!']";
    String[] words=s.split(delim);

  scan.close();
  for(String p : words) {
      if(p != null && p.length() > 0) {
         list.add(p);
      }
  }
      words = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
int x =words.length;
System.out.println(x);
      for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
      { 
          System.out.println(words[i]);
      }
      }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split non-word characters, then you can use regex directly

```
String str = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
String[] Val = str .split("[\\W]");
```

Or if you want to use more explicit then you can use

```
String[] Val = str.split("[' ,@!_.]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your program simple,you can use

```
String st =  "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
String[] tokens = st.split["\\W+"];
```

If you print the tokens,then you will get the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

for me I tried the example :

```
 public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    String [] arrOfStr= s.trim().split("\\s+|,|!|\\.|\\?|_|'|@");  
        scan.close();
       int cmpt =0;

        for (String a : arrOfStr) 
            if(a.isEmpty())
                cmpt++;
        System.out.println(arrOfStr.length-cmpt);

        for (String a : arrOfStr) 
            if(!a.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(a);
 }
}
```